# If duplicates exist, select the value based on another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a large list of zip codes and territories that I've combined from two different data sources.

My columns look like:
zipcode, territory, source

The values might look like:

```
76345, ShiPaTown, Source1
76345, ShiPaTown, Source2
12110, South Park, Source1
12110, Mars, Source2
```

My objective is to only have ONE row per unique zip code and if there's a record for a zip code in BOTH Source1 and Source2, to always take the territory from Source1.

So the previous list would get reduced to:

```
76345, ShiPaTown
12110, SouthPark
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  Here is one approach:

```
select zip, town
from t
where source = 'source1'
union all
select zip, town
from t
where source = 'source2' and
      not exists (select 1 from t as t2 where t2.zip = t.zip and t2.source = 'source1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are either two or one record per `zipcode` then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.zipcode, 
       IIF(ISNULL(t2.territory), t1.territory, t2.territory) AS territory,
       IIF(ISNULL(t2.source), t1.source, t2.source) AS source
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT zipcode, territory, source
   FROM mytable
   WHERE source = 'Source1') AS t2 ON t1.zipcode = t2.zipcode
WHERE t1.source <> 'Source1'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b62bb0/3)

Comment: Hi Giorgos, unfortunately Access does not support the Coalesce function

Comment: `IIF(ISNULL(t2.territory), t1.territory, t2.territory)`

Answer (score 1):

If zip code in each source is unique (no dups in either source, although they may overlap) and you are open to reconsolidating the data, I would make your table from source 1, then make zip a primary key (no dups allowed), then append the data from source 2.  It's a manual workaround, but for only 2 sources it's probably workable.